# Do While loop not coordinating with a Scanner the 2nd time

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I have a project that I need help with. I'm a beginner in programming, and I don't understand this. I'm hoping to get an answer.

```
Scanner reg_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ctr = 0,item = 1;
    char reg_mn = 'y', choice;
    String[] user = new String[item];
    String[] pass = new String[item];
    reg_mn = 'y';
    do {
        System.out.println("[REGISTER]");
        System.out.println("==========");
        System.out.print("Username: ");
        user[ctr] = reg_input.next(); //Line 11
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        pass[ctr] = reg_input.next();
        System.out.println("==========");

        System.out.println("Do you wish to Continue? [Y/N]");
        choice = reg_input.next().charAt(0);

            if (choice == 'y' || choice =='y') {
                item = item + 1;
            } 
            else if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N') {
                reg_mn = 'n';
                item = item + 1;
                return;

            }

        ctr++;
    } while (reg_mn == 'y' || reg_mn == 'Y');
```

> the 1st loop is fine. The problem here is when I type "y" to
>   try and get the 2nd loop, I get an error from the scanner at Line 11

- I researched for problems like this but I seem to get dead ends, that or I haven't read it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have declared a string with the size of an item whose value is 1 initially.
So if you increment the item by 1 but the string array size would not be incremented because it is declared with size 1.

```
String[] user = new String[item];
String[] pass = new String[item];
```

Change like this

```
String[] user = new String[30];
String[] pass = new String[30];
```

You have to declare with some maximum size.

I suggest you use any **java Collections** for this like **HashMap**.
Because here you are declaring the string array with maximum size so it allocated that size however if you are storing only 2 users remaining size would be waste. For this use Collections.

Comment: ahh, I see. is there any way to make it an infinite use?

Comment: Use Java collection HashMap or ArrayList

Comment: ah, I see. I'm still a beginner to java. I don't know what HashMap is - yet. but I'll try doing ArrayList